# How to add a new Parcel inside Parcel Fabric from existing parcel features (ArcObjects)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcobjects, c#, parcel-fabric

I want to create a new parcel in a parcel fabric layer. I have the x, y coordinates for the parcels to be created. I searched around a lot and found really nothing that actually "CREATES" a parcel.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
IPointCollection pts = feat.ShapeCopy as IPointCollection; //an existig polygon from another featureclass used for copying x,y,z..
ICadastralPoints cadPoints = new CadastralPacketClass();
for (int i = 0; i < pts.PointCount; i++)
{
    IPoint p = pts.get_Point(i);
    IGSPoint gsPt = new GSPointClass();
    gsPt.X = p.X;
    gsPt.Y = p.Y;
    gsPt.Z = p.Z;
    gsPt.Type = -1; //just tried when nothing worked..made no difference..
    cadPoints.AddPoint(gsPt);
}

IEnumCELines ceLines = new EnumCELinesClass();

ICadastralLines cadLines = new CadastralPacketClass();
ISegmentCollection segments = feat.ShapeCopy as ISegmentCollection; //an existig polygon from another featureclass used for getting segments
for (int i = 0; i < segments.SegmentCount; i++)
{
    ISegment seg = segments.get_Segment(i);

    IGSLine gsLine = new GSLineClass();
    double bearingDeg = utils.GetBearing(seg.FromPoint, seg.ToPoint);
    gsLine.Bearing = (Math.PI * bearingDeg) / 180;
    gsLine.Distance = seg.Length;

    ceLines.Add(gsLine);
}

IEnumGSLines gsLines = ceLines as IEnumGSLines;

IParcelLineFunctions parcelLineFunctions = new ParcelFunctionsClass();
IConstructParcelFunctions constrParcelFunctions = new ParcelFunctionsClass();
ICadastralPacket m_EditPacket = cadExtension.GetEditPacket();

IEnumGSParcels outputParcels = null;
int peRrorLinePointfrom = -1;
int peRrorLinePointTo = -1;

IGSPlan gsPlan = gsParcel.Plan; //gsParcel is an existing parcel..

constrParcelFunctions.ConstructParcelsFromLines(gsPlan, cadPoints, gsLines, m_EditPacket, 1, ref outputParcels, ref peRrorLinePointfrom, ref peRrorLinePointTo);

IGSParcel resultParcel = outputParcels.Next(); //resultParcel is null now..was expecting this to have some value..
```

Hope anyone would guide me into right direction.

Comment: what is `cadExtension` in `ICadastralPacket m_EditPacket = cadExtension.GetEditPacket();`

Comment: ArcObjects only, no Python?

Comment: @FelixIP - no python

Comment: @FaridCher - it is ICadastralExtension

Comment: @FaridCher - are there any detailed documentations available somewhere regarding parcel fabric Arcobjects API?

Comment: @vinayan, the only documentation available to public is "ArcObjects Help for .NET developers". There is also an open source project regarding parcel-fabric on github: https://github.com/Esri/parcel-fabric-desktop-addins

Comment: There is a question, is it possible to implement this function in a console application, so that the whole process can be automated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure there is a parcel fabric layer present in the map and you have started editing. add the following assemblies to your project if you have not already.

- ESRI.ArcGIS.CadastralUI
- ESRI.ArcGIS.GeoSurvey
- ESRI.ArcGIS.GeoDatabaseExtensions

Use the following class and its methods to create a parcel fabric object from a selected parcel feature in the map. The methods are tested, however, if your found a bug, let me know.

```cs
//@FaridCher at GIS.StackExchange
//can be copied and/or distributed without the express permission

using ESRI.ArcGIS.CadastralUI;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Editor;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.GeoDatabaseExtensions;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.GeoSurvey;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyParcelFabric
{
    class CreateParcelFabric_FromPolygonSelection
    {
        protected override void OnClick()
        {
            var enums = ArcMap.Document.ActiveView.FocusMap.FeatureSelection as IEnumFeature;
            IFeature feat = enums.Next();
            if (feat == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            CreateParcelFabric(feat);
        }

        private void CreateParcelFabric(IFeature polygonFeature)
        {
            try
            {
                UID pUID = new UIDClass();
                pUID.Value = "{114D685F-99B7-4B63-B09F-6D1A41A4DDC1}";
                ICadastralExtensionManager2 pCadExtMan = (ICadastralExtensionManager2)ArcMap.Application.FindExtensionByCLSID(pUID);
                ICadastralEditor pCadEd = (ICadastralEditor)ArcMap.Application.FindExtensionByCLSID(pUID);
                IParcelEditManager pParcEditorMan = (IParcelEditManager)pCadEd;

                IEditor pEd = (IEditor)ArcMap.Application.FindExtensionByName("esri object editor");
                if (pEd.EditState == esriEditState.esriStateNotEditing)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please start editing and try again.");
                    return;
                }

                ICadastralPacketManager pCadPacketMan = (ICadastralPacketManager)pCadEd;
                bool bStartedWithPacketOpen = pCadPacketMan.PacketOpen;
                if (!bStartedWithPacketOpen)
                    pEd.StartOperation();

                //Start map edit session
                ICadastralMapEdit pCadMapEdit = (ICadastralMapEdit)pCadEd;
                pCadMapEdit.StartMapEdit(esriMapEditType.esriMEEmpty, "NewParcel", false);

                //Get job packet
                ICadastralPacket pCadaPacket = pCadPacketMan.JobPacket;

                //Create Plan (new)
                string sPlanName = "My New Plan";
                IGSPlan pGSPlan = null;
                pGSPlan = new GSPlanClass();
                //set values
                pGSPlan.Accuracy = 4;
                pGSPlan.Name = sPlanName;

                //Add the plan to the job packet
                ICadastralPlan pCadaPlan = (ICadastralPlan)pCadaPacket;
                pCadaPlan.AddPlan(pGSPlan);

                //Create Parcel
                ICadastralParcel pCadaParcel = (ICadastralParcel)pCadaPacket;
                IGSParcel pNewGSParcel = new GSParcelClass();
                //Make sure that any extended attributes on the parcel have their default values set
                IGSAttributes pGSAttributes = (IGSAttributes)pNewGSParcel;
                if (pGSAttributes != null)
                {
                    ICadastralObjectSetup pCadaObjSetup = (ICadastralObjectSetup)pParcEditorMan;
                    pCadaObjSetup.AddExtendedAttributes(pGSAttributes);
                    pCadaObjSetup.SetDefaultValues(pGSAttributes);
                }

                //Add the parcel to the packet. (do this before addlines)
                //This will enable us to Acquire the parcel ID,
                //Having the parcel attached to the packet allows InsertLine to function.  
                pCadaParcel.AddParcel(pNewGSParcel);
                pNewGSParcel.Lot = "NewParcel";
                pNewGSParcel.Type = 7;
                //Set Plan (created above)
                IGSPlan thePlan = pCadaPlan.GetPlan(sPlanName);
                pNewGSParcel.Plan = thePlan;


                ICadastralPoints pCadaPoints = (ICadastralPoints)pCadaPacket;
                IMetricUnitConverter pMetricUnitConv = (IMetricUnitConverter)pCadEd;

                ISegmentCollection segments = polygonFeature.ShapeCopy as ISegmentCollection;

                //first segment point of polygon as the start of ParFab
                var pPt1 = segments.get_Segment(0).FromPoint;
                IZAware pZAw = (IZAware)pPt1;
                pZAw.ZAware = true;
                pPt1.Z = 0; //defaulting to 0

                //Convert the point into metric units, and get a new (in-mem) point id
                IGSPoint pGSPointFrom = pMetricUnitConv.SetGSPoint(pPt1);
                pCadaPoints.AddPoint(pGSPointFrom);

                int iID_First_Last = pGSPointFrom.Id;
                int iID1 = iID_First_Last;
                int iID2 = -1;

                int index = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < segments.SegmentCount; i++)
                {
                    ISegment seg = segments.get_Segment(i);

                    double bearingRad = getBearing(seg.FromPoint, seg.ToPoint);

                    bool computeToPoint = true;
                    if (i == segments.SegmentCount - 1)
                        computeToPoint = false;

                    IGSLine pGSLine = CreateGSLine(pMetricUnitConv, pCadaPoints, ref pPt1,
                      iID1, bearingRad, seg.Length, 0, -1, -1, -1, computeToPoint, out iID2);

                    iID1 = iID2;
                    iID2 = -1;

                    if (i == segments.SegmentCount - 1)
                        pGSLine.ToPoint = iID_First_Last;

                    pNewGSParcel.InsertLine(++index, pGSLine);
                }

                //Add radial lines for circular curves
                pNewGSParcel.AddRadialLines();

                //then set join=true on the parcel.
                pNewGSParcel.Joined = true;

                //let the packet know that a change has been made
                pCadPacketMan.SetPacketModified(true);
                try
                {
                    pCadMapEdit.StopMapEdit(true);
                }
                catch
                {
                    if (!bStartedWithPacketOpen)
                        pEd.AbortOperation();
                    return;
                }
                if (!bStartedWithPacketOpen)
                    pEd.StopOperation("New Parcel Fabric");

                pCadPacketMan.PartialRefresh();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private IGSLine CreateGSLine(IMetricUnitConverter MetricConversion, ICadastralPoints CadastralPoints,
      ref IPoint FromPointInToPointOut, int FromPointID, double Direction, double Distance,
      double Radius, int Accuracy, int UserLineType, int Category, bool ComputeToPoint, out int ToPointID)
        {
            //In this function, Radius == 0 means a straight line
            //If the radius is >0 or <0 then the line is a circular curve with Distance as the chord length
            //for curves Bearing means chord bearing
            //negative radius means a curve to the left, positive radius curve to the right
            //for no Accuracy, no Type, or no Category pass in -1
            //Bearing is in north azimuth radians

            IGSLine pLine = new GSLineClass();
            pLine.Bearing = Direction; //direction is in radians north azimuth
            double dConvertedDistance = 0;
            MetricConversion.ConvertDistance(esriCadastralUnitConversionType.esriCUCToMetric, Distance, ref dConvertedDistance);
            pLine.Distance = dConvertedDistance;  //needs to be in meters;

            if (Math.Abs(Radius) > 0)
            {
                MetricConversion.ConvertDistance(esriCadastralUnitConversionType.esriCUCToMetric, Radius, ref dConvertedDistance);
                pLine.Radius = dConvertedDistance;  //needs to be in meters;
            }

            pLine.FromPoint = FromPointID;
            pLine.ToPoint = -1;

            if (Accuracy > -1)
                pLine.Accuracy = Accuracy;
            if (UserLineType > -1)
                pLine.LineType = UserLineType;
            if (Category > -1)
                pLine.Category = (ESRI.ArcGIS.GeoDatabaseExtensions.esriCadastralLineCategory)Category;

            //Make sure that any extended attributes on the line have their default values set
            IGSAttributes pGSAttributes = (IGSAttributes)pLine;
            if (pGSAttributes != null)
            {
                ICadastralObjectSetup pCadaObjSetup = (ICadastralObjectSetup)MetricConversion; //QI
                pCadaObjSetup.AddExtendedAttributes(pGSAttributes);
                pCadaObjSetup.SetDefaultValues(pGSAttributes);
            }

            //Compute the new end point for the line.
            //FromPointInToPointOut is in units of the map projection.
            ICurve pCurv = MetricConversion.GetSurveyedLine(pLine, CadastralPoints, false, FromPointInToPointOut);
            //pCurv is also in the units of the map projection. Convert the end point to metric units.

            FromPointInToPointOut = pCurv.ToPoint;//pass the new To point back out
            FromPointInToPointOut.Z = 0;
            IGSPoint pGSPointTo = MetricConversion.SetGSPoint(FromPointInToPointOut);
            if (ComputeToPoint)
            {
                CadastralPoints.AddPoint(pGSPointTo);
                pLine.ToPoint = pGSPointTo.Id;
                ToPointID = pLine.ToPoint;
            }
            else
                ToPointID = -1;

            if (pCurv is ICircularArc)
            {
                ICircularArc pCircArc = (ICircularArc)pCurv;
                IPoint pCtrPt = pCircArc.CenterPoint;
                IZAware pZAw = (IZAware)pCtrPt;
                pZAw.ZAware = true;
                pCtrPt.Z = 0;
                IGSPoint pGSCtrPt = MetricConversion.SetGSPoint(pCtrPt);
                CadastralPoints.AddPoint(pGSCtrPt);
                pLine.CenterPoint = pGSCtrPt.Id;
            }

            return pLine;
        }

        private double getBearing(IPoint fromPoint, IPoint toPoint)
        {
            ILine line = new LineClass();
            line.PutCoords(fromPoint, toPoint);
            double angle = line.Angle;
            return Math.PI / 2 - angle;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot..I never really expected anyone could answer this..such an authentic answer I even doubt you are the developer of the parcel fabric SDK..your comments beat the comments(virtually empty) in the API documentation.

Comment: The way I guessed the API would work was entirely wrong :D